# How to deal with UnsafeMutableBufferPointer?

Tags: swift, buffer, unsafe, unsafemutablepointer, unsafemutablebufferpointer

I would like to know how to deal with **UnsafeMutableBufferPointer** when It comes to initialize It as an empty array and fill It with chunks of `[UInt8]` ?

I tried to loop over the chunks and store every bytes by doing:

```
for (i, byte) in chunk.enumerated() {
   buffer[i] = byte
}
```

But I’m wondering if there’s a more convenient way to achieve this (maybe less memory consuming) ?

Comment: There are several options, the best one depends on what you're planning to do with the resulting `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer`.

Comment: I aim to incrementally decode an image data with `ImageIO` using `Data.init(buffer: UnsafeMutableBufferPointer)` and `CGImageSourceUpdateData`